# Need help integrating external google maps navigation in Ionic 2 application

Tags: cordova, google-maps, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to integrate external google maps navigation with ride distance and time. I have a method for it provided by phonegap-launch-navigator. The code for the method is as follows;

```
navigate()
{
    let options: LaunchNavigatorOptions = {
      start: this.start
    };
    LaunchNavigator.navigate(this.destination, options)
        .then(
            success => alert('Launched navigator'),
            error => alert('Error launching navigator: ' + error)
    );
  }
```

and my submit method is like;

```
 submit() {
    let that = this;
    this.map.getCameraPosition().then(res => {
      let callback = that.navParams.get("callback")
      callback(res.target).then(() => {
        this._navController.pop();
      });
    })
  }
```

which gives a latlng.

I have a navigate button on the front end which invokes this method. The start  and destination takes latlng. I don't know how to provide latlng from google maps api and pass them in the navigate method. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var lat = "1.39";
var lng = "103.84";

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);   
var coord = String(latlng);                      //(1.39, 103.84)
var result = coord.substring(1, coord.length-1); //1.39, 103.84
result = result.replace(/ /g,'');                //1.39,103.84
var list = result.split(",");                    //["1.39","103.84"]

var latnavi = list[0];
var lngnavi = list[1];

navigate(){
  LaunchNavigator.navigate([latnavi, lngnavi], options)
        .then(
            success => alert('Launched navigator'),
            error => alert('Error launching navigator: ' + error)
    );
}
```

Don't really understand how your `submit()` is link with `navigate()` so if I have understood wrongly do let me know.

Comment: Submit() is only linked in a way to navigate that it grabs the current coordinates in the centre of the screen. I want to get the latlng from that and use them in navigate. I am not sure how I will do that. Every time it will be different coordinates when you press submit and would reflect the centre of the screen at that time.  Thanks for your help.